# To integrate Google calendar in my web site

Tags: api, calendar

**Task** - There is an event form in my web site and fill up of the form wants to create an event in Google calendar.

I downloaded the Google calendar API code - "google-api-php-client-0.5.0.tar.gz" and got the info of "Client ID for web applications" and "Simple API Access". Please note the "Simple API access status is **Inactive**, not sure why the status is Inactive and do not know how to make it as "Active" one. Please comment it.

I installed the Google calendar in my local machine (localhost, not in any domain - www.mydomain.com) and configured the Client Id, Client Secret, Redirect URL and Developer Key in /calendar-root/examples/plus/index.php

When I exexute the example PHP file, I am getting an error - "Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri"
Please note I run the file from localhost i.e http://localhost:2020/gcalendar/examples/plus/index.php

Please help me how to add new event from web form in PHP and Is it possible to run the Google API code from local machine. Also pease let me know if you have any reference links for this integration in PHP

Thanks

Comment: I update the client id, secret and API key in /src/config.php and now it fetch the list of events in http://localhost:2020/gcalendar/examples/calendar/simple.php from Google calendar.

Still checking a method to insert new event to the Google calendar from PHP web form. :)

Comment: I found another link.. It is superb.. it has all the functionality to add, edit, view and delete but it required Zend Framework.
I am looking for this same functionality without Zend framework..

I keep on checking.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question and more can be found at http://AmazeWebs.com

Try using a service account, look at this demo for an example: http://amazewebs.com/demo